# How do I feature-detect for a CSS pseudoselector?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a custom `input[type='range']`, and need to introduce some specific behavior for the browsers that DON'T provide native CSS pseudo-selectors for the "progress" section of the range input. In this case, it's Chrome and Safari.

Firefox: `input[type='range']::-moz-range-progress`

Edge / IE11: `input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower`

I'd like to use feature-detection over browser-detection. Is there a way to detect whether a browser supports a given CSS pseudoselector?

Comment: My `getComputedStyle` attempt won't work in Chrome since it is always returning something truthy even if the psudo doesn't exist.

Comment: What about `@supports`?

Comment: There's a pretty good chance Modernizr has a test for this, OR, at least, a similar test that can be adapted for your use.  I would look through the list of detects on their website and find something similar.  I don't see a test for the input type `range`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. `@supports` won't work unfortunately because I need the check in my JS, and I need to introduce the behavior only if the selectors are *not* supported. Modernizr seems to have one that checks for `input[type='range']` support but not for the pseudoselectors.